# While deploying spring project I am getting dependency injection error

Tags: java, spring

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'commonUtilController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ems.service.common.CommonUtilService com.ems.controller.common.CommonUtilController.commonUtilService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ems.service.common.CommonUtilService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ems.service.common.CommonUtilService com.ems.controller.common.CommonUtilController.commonUtilService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ems.service.common.CommonUtilService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ems.service.common.CommonUtilService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 24 more
```

---

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>ems</groupId>
        <artifactId>ems</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>ems-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ems-web Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring-version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <jackson-version>1.9.13</jackson-version>
        <log4j-version>1.2.17</log4j-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ems</groupId>
            <artifactId>ems-services</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ems</groupId>
            <artifactId>ems-dto</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- data conversions -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20141113</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId> 
            <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>commons-digester</groupId> 
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId> <version>2.1</version> </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>ems-web</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-compiler-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [3.1,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>ems</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>

        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ems</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
       <!--  <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:ems-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param> -->
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ems</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/ems-servlet.xml,/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

<listener>
   <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener> 

<!-- Spring Security -->
     <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

---

ems-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Copyright 2010 The myBatis Team Licensed under the Apache License, Version 
    2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with 
    the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed 
    under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES 
    OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for 
    the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License. -->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:websocket="http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket http://www.springframework.org/schema/websocket/spring-websocket-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <import resource="classpath*:/ems-services.xml" />  

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean class ="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ems" >
</context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

---

controller

```
package com.ems.controller.common;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.ems.dto.common.BaseDto;
import com.ems.dto.common.StatesDto;
import com.ems.service.common.CommonUtilService;
import com.ems.util.ResponseEntityBuilder;

/**
 * @author Shivaling Gondhali
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"/commonutil"})
public class CommonUtilController {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CommonUtilController.class);

    @Autowired
    private CommonUtilService commonUtilService;

    public CommonUtilService getCommonUtilService() {
        return commonUtilService;
    }

    public void setCommonUtilService(CommonUtilService commonUtilService) {
        this.commonUtilService = commonUtilService;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return ResponseEntity<BaseDto>
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/getstates" }, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<BaseDto> getStates() {
        logger.info("Entered into getstates");
        StatesDto statesDto = commonUtilService.getState();
        logger.info("Exited from getstates");
        return ResponseEntityBuilder.buildResponseHeader(statesDto, HttpStatus.OK, null);
    }

}
```

---

UtilCommonService

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.ems.service.common;

import com.ems.dto.common.StatesDto;

/**
 * @author Shivaling Gondhali
 *
 */
public interface CommonUtilService {

    public StatesDto getState();

}
```

---

CommonUtilServiceImpl

```
package com.ems.service.impl.common;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.ems.dto.common.StatesDto;
import com.ems.service.common.CommonUtilService;
import com.ems.service.helper.common.CommonUtilServiceHelper;

/**
 * @author Shivaling Gondhali
 *
 */
public class CommonUtilServiceImpl implements CommonUtilService {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CommonUtilServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private CommonUtilServiceHelper commonUtilServiceHelper;

    /**
     * @return LocationsDto
     */
    public StatesDto getState() {
        logger.info("Entered into getState");
        StatesDto statesDto = commonUtilServiceHelper.getState();
        logger.info("Exited from getState");
        return statesDto;
    }
}
```

---

StateDto

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.ems.dto.common;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author ADMIN
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class StatesDto extends BaseDto {

    private List<StateDto> states;

    public List<StateDto> getStates() {
        return states;
    }

    public void setStates(List<StateDto> states) {
        this.states = states;
    }

    /**
     * Add stateDto objects to stateDtoList objects.
     * 
     * @param stateDto
     * @return void
     */
    public void addStates(StateDto stateDto) {
        if (this.states == null) {
            this.states = new ArrayList<StateDto>();
        }
        this.states.add(stateDto);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Where is your code? Right now it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You show the pom-file. But the exception comes from Java [Spring]: NoSuchMethodError.

Comment: `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`, auto-wiring gone wrong!

Comment: how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Add annotation `@Service` for the Class `CommonUtilServiceImpl`

```
@Service
public class CommonUtilServiceImpl implements CommonUtilService {
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring is not bale to find the CommonUtilService dependancy. Please add @Service annotation on CommonUtilServiceImpl.

```
@Service
public class CommonUtilServiceImpl implements CommonUtilService
```